# SVNkit 1.7.8 JAVA Basic stuff

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

Is there any webpage that holds basic programs, which are using Java SVN kit, that do simple stuff with svn like: co, info, update etc.

I'm reading API, but I need just some simple stuff for beginning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Um... how bout the SvnKit website which has example code:

[SvnKit examples](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_A_Working_Copy)